# How to write repetitive [onClick] statements into single line in JQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

How to write following statements into one line?

```
$("#pushkar").on("click", function () {
        gula.hideUnhide("#pushkarDiv", "#pushkar", "#pushkar");
    });
    $("#rashkar").on("click", function () {
        gula.hideUnhide("#rashkarDiv", "#rashkar", "#rashkar");
    });
    $("#kashkar").on("click", function () {
        gula.hideUnhide("#kashkarDiv", "#kashkar", "#kashkar");
    });
    $("#fuskar").on("click", function () {
        gula.hideUnhide("#fuskarDiv", "#fuskar", "#fuskar");
    });
    $("#ashke").on("click", function () {
        gula.hideUnhide("#ashkeDiv", "#ashke", "#ashke");
    });
```

I have around 20 statements like above and all are consuming lot of space.

I am told to stop repetition and make one line for all; which accumulate each button id.

Is it better strategy to write it in single line? Will not it harms readability?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
$("#pushkar, #rashkar, #kashkar, #fuskar, #ashke").on("click", function () {
    var id = "#" + this.id;
    gula.hideUnhide(id + "Div", id, id);
});
```

BTW, it is always better to keep a common class. then you can do like this:

```
$(".commonClass").on("click", function () {
    var id = "#" + this.id;
    gula.hideUnhide(id + "Div", id, id);
});
```

NOTE: You are sending same argument twice which seems unnecessary but I kept it that way only.

Just a suggestions to you, there seems no need of passing three arguments. having a single argument will work great. For example:

```
hideUnhide(id){
    var divId = id + "Div";
    // other code here
}
```

and then later in click events:

```
gula.hideUnhide("#" + this.id);
```

Comment: Looking acceptable way of doing it. Because writing each id in $() might be confusing and if id grows to 40 then it will look bad. So making class on button and us its id is suitable way. Let me implement it, if i will find issue then will ask here. Thanks for help :)

Comment: @fatherazrael BTW, why are you sending the same argument twice?

Comment: Yes. You are correct. :) Actually, one is custom attribute value and other is ID of div and third one is ID of button itself. As custom attribute have same value of id, i can pass the same but if it is different in some case? Thats why kept like this. Thanks for caught.

Comment: What if function is like $("#pushkar").on("click", function () {
        gula.hideUnhide("#pushkaravDiv", "#pushkara", "#pushkara");
    });, i think then your way will not work?

Comment: @fatherazrael you can add custom attributes to each element, then it will work.

Answer (score 2):

You can add multiple event handlers on multiple elements separated by comma **,** as shown below.

```
$('#pushkar, #rashkar, #kashkar, #fuskar, #ashke').on('click', function() {
    var divId = $(this).attr('id'); // Get the id of clicked element

    gula.hideUnhide('#' + divId + 'Div', '#' + divId, '#' + divId);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Use multiple selectors in jquery **$('selector1,selector2,selector3'...selectorn)**

```
$("#pushkar, #rashkar, #kashkar, #fuskar, #ashke").on("click", function () {
        var id = $(this).attr('id');
        gula.hideUnhide("#"+id+"Div", "#"+id, "#"+id);
 });
```